# round robin scheduling with i/o

Tags: c, performance, time, scheduler, round-robin

I am implementing round robin scheduling with given I/O within processes. This means there are some processes that wait for I/O interrupt as well. Here's an example:

Process 1
    arrival time-100
    burst time-300
    then it has two i/o events within it
    i/o event 1
    arrival time-arrival time of process one + 10
    burst time-50
    i/o event 2
    arrival time-arrival time of process one + 15
    burst time-20

Process 2
    arrival time-200
    burst time-300
    then it has one i/o events within it
    i/o event 1
    arrival time-arrival time of process two + 30
    burst time-50

Iam using time quantum of 50 and there are 10 processes like that with or without i/o events

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
# include "rr_multilevel.h"
void round_robin_scheduling(int time_quantum){
    int burst_times[] = {10,16,5,20,18};
    int arrival_times[] = {0,1,2,3,4};
    int remaining_processes = 
    sizeof(burst_times)/sizeof(burst_times[0]);
    int time,count;
    int total_number_process = sizeof(burst_times)/burst_times[0];
    for (time=0,count=0; remaining_processes!=0;) {
        if (burst_times[count]<=time_quantum && burst_times[count]>0) {
            time += burst_times[count];
            burst_times[count] = 0;
        }
        else if (burst_times[count]>time_quantum){
            burst_times[count]-=time_quantum;
            time += time_quantum;
        }
        if (burst_times[count] == 0) {
            remaining_processes--;
        }
        if (count == total_number_process-1) {
            count = 0;
        }
        else if(arrival_times[count+1]<=time)
            count++;
        else
            count=0;
    }
    printf("total time consumed using this time quantum is %d \n",time);
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    int t_q = 10;
    round_robin_scheduling(t_q);
    return 0;
}
```

I don't know how to make these i/o events into play I have to find the total completion time

Comment: Sorry but the description of your issue and your answer are not very clear. What exactly are you asking for ? Also there are plenty of small and free OSes that provide round-robin scheduling and thread functionalities. Is it a real project you are working on or just some college homework ?

Comment: it is a part of some project what i am after is there is a process and it has some i/o events and there are many other processes like that so i have to find the total completion time with the given time quantum

Comment: what my process looks like is                                                                           process 1 200 { i/o 110 hd 1600}